# Show splash screen by Gradle

Tags: java, gradle, ant

When start my java application I show splash screen usging the next Ant target:

```
<target name="default" description="run program via classpath">
    <echo message="var.distribute.version.type=${var.distribute.version.type}" />
    <ac:switch value="${var.distribute.version.type}">
        <ac:case value="${prop.distribute.version.lite}">
            <ac:runtarget target="compile-lite" />
        </ac:case>
        <ac:case value="${prop.distribute.version.pro}">
            <ac:runtarget target="compile-pro" />
        </ac:case>
    </ac:switch>
    <echo>Running with classpath=${toString:run.classpath}</echo>
    <java classname="${main.class}" fork="true">
        <jvmarg value="-splash:${images.dir}/splash.png" />
        <classpath refid="run.classpath" />
    </java>
</target>
```

Nice. It's work. But now I need to do the same by Gradle. How show splash screen by Gradle?

I run my java app by this:

```
gradle run
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Show splash screen by Gradle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72582831/show-splash-screen-by-gradle)

Comment: @itfedorovsa No

Comment: There are at least two options. One is to set `applicationDefaultJvmArgs`, which you can see an example of at [The Application Plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/application_plugin.html). Or you could configure the `run` task directly, which is a [`JavaExec`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.JavaExec.html).